# Quickest way to dry wet floor

Tags: thermodynamics, convection, humidity

I have spilled around one liter of water to wooden floor. I'm afraid wood will deform and pop out.
What would be quickest way to dry it? I have wiped out what I could, but some water passed between the planks.

Conditions: It's summer time. Outside temperature is 19 degC, relative humidity is 85%, dew point is 16 degC. Spill is in the corner of a room, one meter from balcony door, always in shade. It is cloudy, and will be for the rest of the day. Room volume is around 35 cubic meters. Air conditioner can blow 90 degrees to the direction of a spill.

Options to dry it:

1. Open the balcony door, and let it dry naturally
2. Close all doors. Set air conditioner to heating, in an attempt to reduce relative humidity and promote drying. Total amount of moisture in the air will, I assume, remain constant (please ignore "seeping" around doors). Let's assume AC can maintain 25 degC in the room.
3. Close all doors. Set air conditioner to cooling, in order to forcefully remove moisture. Let's assume 18 degC. I do not know what will be relative humidity under these conditions.
4. Combination of the above: door open, AC working

If you can provide (rough) calculation to compare drying times, please do. If not, I'll happily accept textual explanation. I've learned thermodynamics a lot, but 20 years ago. I still have basic grasp of concepts, but I'm totally rusty. This is more of an exercise for my middle school son.

This is my first question on Stack Exchange, so feel free to correct the "procedural" stuff.

Comment: air flow. Blow with a fan ASAP. Also, osmosis: rice, saw dust, salt (maybe not).

Comment: Thanks JEB, I'm aware of that. I've specifically posted a question with above conditions and equipment (no hair dryer, just AC, with negligible flow over the spill), because I can't figure it out theoretically. I do not have real problem (spill has already dried), this is more of a mental exercise of rusty mechanical engineer :).